# Could not find builder-3.4.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.4.2)

Tags: android, gradle

When i run command `react-native run-android`, i get this error :

```
Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find builder-3.4.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.4.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.4.2/builder-3.4.2.jar
```

my grade version is 3.4.2

How i can resolve this error?